# How to count the number of rows after filtering an advanceddatagrid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I am trying to count the number of rows in an advanceddatagrid
I need a function which could count all item with or without filterFunction.

I tried some solution but none works. The best that I found, is to expand all items and use a cursor for looping.
But, when we have a lot of data, expanding all is not a good solution.

Do you have an idea on how to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Well you provide the data via dataProvider, right? Then why not count it there?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I came up was investigating `dataProvider`

```
// current not expanded data row lenght
grid.dataProvider.lenght;

// expanded length
// I assume you use xml as your data provider
// then you can count it like this
xmlListTotalSize(new XMLList(grid.dataProvider.source.source));
// or with casts
xmlListTotalSize(new XMLList((IHierarchicalCollectionView(view.grid.dataProvider).source as HierarchicalData).source));
```

and xmllist traversal function might look something like this:

```
private static function xmlListTotalSize(x:XMLList):int
{
    var i:int = x.length();
    for each(var xChild:XML in x.children())
        i += xmlListTotalSize(xChild.children());
    return i;
}
```